# Fix the missing bottom border when export a range to the email body of new message?

Tags: html, excel, vba, automation, outlook

I am using a code to export any range from excel file and insert ( as table ) on the body of outlook new message.
It works with one issue, that the `bottom border is always missing` after inserted on outlook mail body. 
**Note**: If I changed manually the height or width of the table then the bottom border appears normally. 
The code is long to post here ,So I will show the part of HTML which I think the problem exists. 
As always, grateful for all your help.
[image]

```
'--- Create a New Email
 
    Set objOutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set objNewEmail = objOutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
 
'--- Read the HTML File data and insert into the Email Body
 
    objNewEmail.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
    objNewEmail.Display
 
    Set objTextStream = objFileSystem.OpenTextFile(strTempHTMLFile)
 
    Strbody = "<h4> </h4>" & "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <span style='font-size:11.5pt'> "
 
    objNewEmail.HTMLBody = Strbody & "<table style='Margin-Left:5pt'>" & _
                           objTextStream.ReadAll & "</Table>" & "<br>" & objNewEmail.HTMLBody
```

Comment: I think it would be good to show us the way of html file building. When I played with such an issue, I adapted a little Ron de Bruin's code to deliver the range to be attached in a way that placing it in a html `Table` to not be necessary ... Don't you use such a code (`RangeToHTML`, I mean)?

Comment: @FaneDuru yes I used `Ron de Bruin's code` , but I adapted a little. It is very long to post here.

Comment: You, probably must adapt it deeper, then...

Comment: Not necessarily... I only cannot understand why you need to place the processed range (html) in a table. Only to be able to read the previous `HTMLBody` after it? I maybe cannot concentrate as it should. I am looking to an interesting tenis match from Wimbledon... Is the missing border applied in `RangeToHTML` function?

Comment: @FaneDuru , actually it is not a big issue for me, I just post this question to learn.

Comment: OK, but for the same reason you may answer my clarification question... ** Is the missing border applied in `RangeToHTML` function**?

Comment: @FaneDuru ,sure there is a piece of code to add border to range (in excel) in the same sub , I am not a beginner to forgot this.

Comment: It is not a matter of forgetting... If you forgot it, how to appear if you change the table dimensions? I am not familiarized with such tables in html and I was asking myself if they are only places to keep something (like I thought), or they show also a border, even if html code does not do anything from this point of view... In the meantime I tried playing with that way of placing the range in a table but I cannot reproduce your problem. Is it possible that the range in discussion to be larger/bigger than the outlook window to keep it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I played with table borders, color, width and html created the border as I wanted. But I could not reproduce your problem. Then, I start playing with the cells borders applied when the range to be placed in the mail body received borders. When I placed such **thin** borders, your problem has been reproduced. My initial code placed **xlThick** borders...

So, please use the next simple function to add borders on the range to be exported cells:

```
Sub PlaceBorders(rng As Range)
 Dim i As Long
     For i = 7 To 12
        With rng.Borders(i)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .ColorIndex = 0
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .Weight = xlThick 'if here you will use xlThin, only in this case the problem you describe appears...
        End With
        Next i
    End Sub
```

Don't ask me why it's happening....

Comment: You're correct ,I just adapted my code to make the bottom border `xlThick` instead of xlthin and that fixed the issue

Comment: I played with borders index and found out that the bottom one has `index 4 also 9`.
Anyhow, up voted for your cleverness to reproduce my issue although I didn’t provide my full code on question.

Comment: @Waleed I am not sure I understand what you mean... `.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)` is identic with `.Borders(9)`. You can find [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlbordersindex) the border indexes enumeration. Some time ago I could see this page an being inspired to use the borders index in a loop... I never checked if Microsoft allows index of `4` for the bottom border... I usually search for Microsoft documentation. For instance, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.constants) you can find most of used (Excel) constants.

Comment: @Waleed  So you can use `xlChecker`, `xlColor3`, `xlDesktop` and so on... They are `Long` constants considered by the code. Their name only help the programmer to better remember a specific constant in a specific context...

Answer (score 1):

i found this solution:

I added in the funcion:

```
RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0", _
                      "table border=0 cellpadding=1 cellspacing=1")
```

after the line:

```
RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                      "align=left x:publishsource=")
```

in this way the buttom border is present.
This is my correct function:

```
Function RangetoHTML(rngM As Range)
    Dim obj As Object
    Dim txtstr As Object
    Dim File As String
    Dim WB As Workbook
    File = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"
    
    rngM.Copy
    Set WB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    
    With WB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
         Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
         On Error GoTo 0
    End With
           
    With WB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=File, _
         Sheet:=WB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=WB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With
    Set obj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set txtstr = obj.GetFile(File).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
   
    RangetoHTML = txtstr.ReadAll
    txtstr.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")
    
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0", _
                          "table border=0 cellpadding=1 cellspacing=1")
                          
         
    WB.Close savechanges:=False
    Kill File
    Set txtstr = Nothing
    Set obj = Nothing
    Set WB = Nothing
End Function
```